# Assigning DDnames by the user in jcl

Tags: cobol, jcl

I want to specify the ddname of the file "ABC.DEF.XXX" in which XXX is the input given by the user through sysin in jcl.How it can be achieved?

Comment: How is the user passing the information to the JCL?

Comment: Dynamic allocation. Find out which method your site uses, or if not using already get someone to decide which method your site should use.

Comment: Why does the user enter data via a Sysin ???

Comment: @BruceMartin and how?!

Answer (score 6):

Please understand there is a big difference between...

- what is technically possible
- what is allowed in your shop
- what is likely to provide a robust and maintainable solution given your requirements

These are three very different things.  Some of us answering questions here on StackOverflow have life experiences that make us reticent about answering questions regarding what is technically possible absent any mention of what is allowed in your shop or what the actual business requirement is that is being solved.

Mainframes have been around for over half a century, and many shops have standard solutions to technical problems.  Sometimes the solution is "don't do that, and here's what *we* do instead."  Working against the recommendations of your technical staff, or your shop standards, is career limiting.

One of the potentially unintended consequences of what you propose is that accesses to `ABC.DEF.XXX` will not be found by scans of JCL.  This may cause grief for those doing impact analysis.

That said, two solutions to your problem come to mind that fall into the "what is technically possible" category.

1. You can write an Assembler subroutine to use `SVC99`, also known as `DYNALLOC`, which is the dynamic allocation routine on z/OS. Documentation is voluminous, see the IBM Knowledge Center for z/OS and look under z/OS MVS -> z/OS MVS Programming: Authorized Assembler Services -> Dynamic Allocation.
2. You can construct the parameters to call the C runtime routine `dynalloc()` to dynamically allocate your file.

Be advised that in either case, the solution *really should* include robust and flexible error handling.

Typically one does not dynamically assign a DD name, and a DSN which must be assigned at runtime is accomplished with a symbolic parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You might check if the &SYSUID. symbol is available for use at your shop.  If so, it will be expanded to the ID of the submitting user when you specify AAA.BBB.&SYSUID.

Some shops will also propagate other symbols, some will not allow any, it really just depends.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, there is a slightly different way to do this that doesn't involve DYNALLOC (SVC 99).

The drawback of DYNALLOC is that your job could wait for resources quite a while, tying up resources (such as a batch initiator) while conflicts are resolved. For example, if the dataset or volume you need aren't immediately available, it's possible to wait indefinitely, depending on how you code your DYNALLOC.

If all you need to do is change the name of a dataset, you can sometimes do it with RDJFCB and OPEN TYPE=J. The JFCB (Job File Control Block) is how z/OS knows about an allocated dataset...the DSN and most of the information from the dataset label are stored in there. The RDJFCB macro gets you access to the JFCB, and then OPEN TYPE=J gives you a way to modify the system-built JFCB - for instance, to change the dataset name to something you compute, rather than what was in the JCL.

A common way to do this is to just have a DD statement with the basic allocation data - it doesn't even need a DSN (the system will cook up a temporary DSN for you if you don't specify one in JCL). Your program uses OPEN TYPE=J to modify the JFCB, changing the dataset name to whatever you like. This is sort of the best of both worlds - you get to do what you want, and the system gets to resolve any resource conflicts before your job even starts.

There are some authorization requirements for OPEN TYPE=J, and it's certainly not for beginners, but if you're interested, it's all documented. Anyone trying this will definitely learn a lot about z/OS in the process!